# Iterate and group the objects using map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

**Check for the decimal id and group them accordingly.**

Below are the sample and recommended JSON's

**Sample JSON**

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "1.1.1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "1.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "1.3.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "2.3"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "3.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "3.5"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "4.2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Would like to iterate and Re-structure the above JSON into below recommended format.

**Logic:** Should check the id(with and without decimals) and group them based on the number.

**For Example:**

```
1, 1.1, 1.2.3, 1.4.5 => data1: [{id: 1},{id: 1.1}....] 
2, 2.3, 2.3.4 => data2: [{id: 2},{id: 2.3}....]
3, 3.1 => data3: [{id: 3},{id: 3.1}]
```

**Recommended JSON**

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "data1": [
                {
                    "name": "Download",
                    "id": "1.1.1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Download",
                    "id": "1.2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Download",
                    "id": "1.3.2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "data2": [
                {
                    "name": "Download",
                    "id": "2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Download",
                    "id": "2.3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "data3": [
                {
                    "name": "Download",
                    "id": "3.2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Download",
                    "id": "3.5"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "data4": [
                {
                    "name": "Download",
                    "id": "4.2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried the below solution but it doesn't group the object

```
var formatedJSON = [];
results.map(function(d,i) {
    formatedJSON.push({
        [data+i]: d
    })
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this. The idea is to create a key-value pair for each `data1`, `data2` etc so that values in this object are the values you need in the final array. Then use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get those as an array.

```js
const sampleJson = {"results":[{"name":"Download","id":"1.1.1"},{"name":"Download","id":"1.2"},{"name":"Download","id":"1.3.2"},{"name":"Download","id":"2"},{"name":"Download","id":"2.3"},{"name":"Download","id":"3.2"},{"name":"Download","id":"3.5"},{"name":"Download","id":"4.2"}]}

const grouped = sampleJson.results.reduce((a, v) => {
    const key = `data${parseInt(v.id)}`;
    (a[key] = a[key] || {[key]: []})[key].push(v);
    return a;
},{});

console.log({results: Object.values(grouped)})
```

One liner / Code-golf:

```js
let s={"results":[{"name":"Download","id":"1.1.1"},{"name":"Download","id":"1.2"},{"name":"Download","id":"1.3.2"},{"name":"Download","id":"2"},{"name":"Download","id":"2.3"},{"name":"Download","id":"3.2"},{"name":"Download","id":"3.5"},{"name":"Download","id":"4.2"}]},k;

console.log({results:Object.values(s.results.reduce((a,v)=>(k=`data${parseInt(v.id)}`,(a[k] = a[k]||{[k]:[]})[k].push(v),a),{}))})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
var data = {
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "1.1.1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "1.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "1.3.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "2.3"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "3.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "3.5"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "4.2"
        }
    ]
};


let newSet = new Set();

data.results.forEach(e => {
  let key = e.id.substring(0, e.id.indexOf('.'));
  console.log(key);
  if (newSet.has(key) == false) {
    newSet.add(key);
    newSet[key] = [];
    }
   newSet[key].push(e.id);
});


console.log(newSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd do it:

```js
var data = {
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "1.1.1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "1.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "1.3.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "2.3"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "3.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "3.5"
        },
        {
            "name": "Download",
            "id": "4.2"
        }
    ]
};

var newData = {
  "results": {}
};

data.results.forEach(item => {
  var num = item.id.slice(0, 1);
  if (newData.results["data" + num]) {
    newData.results["data" + num].push(item);
  } else {
    newData.results["data" + num] = [item];
  }
})

data = newData;
console.log(data);
```

What this does is it iterates through each item in `results`, gets the number at the front of this item's `id`, and checks if an array of the name `data-{num}` exists. If the array exists, it's pushed. If it doesn't exist, it's created with the item.

Comment: `results` should be an array, not an object :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = getInput();

let output = input.reduce((acc, curr)=>{
  let {id} = curr;
  let majorVersion = 'name' + id.split('.')[0];
  if(!acc[majorVersion]) acc[majorVersion]= [];
  acc[majorVersion].push(curr);
  return acc;
},{})
  
console.log(output)
  
  
  
function getInput(){
  return [
  {
      "name": "Download",
      "id": "1.1.1"
  },
  {
      "name": "Download",
      "id": "1.2"
  },
  {
      "name": "Download",
      "id": "1.3.2"
  },
  {
      "name": "Download",
      "id": "2"
  },
  {
      "name": "Download",
      "id": "2.3"
  },
  {
      "name": "Download",
      "id": "3.2"
  },
  {
      "name": "Download",
      "id": "3.5"
  },
  {
      "name": "Download",
      "id": "4.2"
  }

  ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution with RegEx for finer control as it would differentiate easily between 1 and 11.
Also this will make sure that even if the same version comes in end(say 1.9 in end) it will put it back in data1.

```
let newArr2 = ({ results }) =>
  results.reduce((acc, item) => {
    let key = "data" + /^(\d+)\.?.*/.exec(item.id)[1];
    let found = acc.find(i => key in i);
    found ? found[key].push(item) : acc.push({ [key]: [item] });
    return acc;
  }, []);
```